# Proper verb to denote 'consistent-ize'

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb I could use to condense "make consistent" or "consistentize" in one word?  E.g.

> another item to  across different groups in our process is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a verb meaning "to make similar"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187101/is-there-a-verb-meaning-to-make-similar)

Comment: Sure would be nice if we could combine this Q and its As with http://english.stackexchange.com/q/187101/49890

Comment: I've been using "consistify" and "consistification" but those are not words, which is why I'm reading this page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use > **standardise**

> standardize [/ standardise]
>
> verb [(1) used with object]
>
> to bring to or make of an established standard size, weight, quality,
> strength, or the like:
>
> - *to standardize manufactured parts.*

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/standardise)]

Comment: The American standard spelling here is standardize.

Answer (score 11):

#### Normalize

> Bring or return to a normal or standard condition or state.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/normalize)]

Answer (score 8):

Another one for the bin:

[Homogenize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homogenize)

> 1. to make uniform or similar, as in composition or function: to homogenize school systems.

Answer (score 6):

*Harmonize* means this in some cases where *regulate* or *reconcile* do not.

Answer (score 1):

Regulate.

> Control or supervise (something, esp. a company or business activity) by means of rules and regulations.

Reconcile:

> to make consistent

As defined by Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly **[unify](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/unify)**

> to make things work well together

or **[integrate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrate)**

> to form, coordinate, or blend into a functioning or unified whole

or perhaps even **[consubstantiate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consubstantiate)**

> to unite or become united in one common substance, nature, or essence

(although the last has certian religious overtones).